# Delayed Image load not working / menu toggle

Tags: load, fade

I am trying to use thie http://jsfiddle.net/4uqzA/1/ in order to make the images such as on this page: http://www.callumritchie.com/work.html fade in one by one. But it doesnt seem to work

Also... If anyone knows how I would make the menu closed on page load (i.e the menu options at the top not showing -it seems to be toggled open on page load but I want it closed)

Thanks!

```
$("div.image-div").each(function(index) {
$(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace `div.image-div` (in the javascript example) by `div.box` (corresponding to your class name) if you did not already.

(edit)
More precisely, you can put this in your `script.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.box").fadeOut(0);
    $("div.box").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(100*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: How about the CSS? I added display:none to .box like in the fiddle. Thanks